# Is it fine to substitute $x=t$ back to this function?

Tags: functions

I want to ask, if there is a function:
$$f(t)=t+\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(x+t)\,dx,$$ where f is a function.

I substituted $x=t$, and get:
$$f(x)=x+\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(2x)\,dx.$$
Can I do so? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: $x$ is a dummy variable. That's not how it works. The symbol $x$ can be replaced by anything.

Comment: @Peter Foreman Sir，May I know what is the mistake here? Thank you very much.

Comment: the problem is that $t$ in the integral should be treated as constant and you made it a variable.

Comment: @HenryCai $x$ is not a number so $f$ cannot be evaluated at this point.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, now I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Otherwise we could do things like this:

$$x\log x = \int_1^x\frac{x}{t}\,dt \stackrel{\rm wrong}= \int_1^x\frac{x}{x}dx = \int_1^xdx=x-1.$$
This creates a problem called *variable capture*. I replaced $t$ with $x$, but then the other $x$ in the numerator is "captured" by the integral, when it should just be a constant. If I change that to some other symbol, and then switch it back later once the integral is evaluated, then that would be okay.

Look at [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/66076/44283) for more examples.

It is important to understand that the integral [*binds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) a variable.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Is an upvote sir

Comment: Sir, So we cannot substitute other variables to the variable being used in the integral to make the integral easier, right? thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for the upvote @HenryCai, but someone else downvoted, that's why I have a score of 0.

Comment: Not in this way, no. There is [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), but that is something different to simply relabelling variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask one more thing. Can I say that f'(x) = 1?  Cuz the derivative of the definite integral is 0, so we do not need to care about it.

Comment: No, you cannot. The variable $x$ will vanish when the integration is performed, it is a "dummy variable", so you're right, there will be no $x$. But there is still a $t$ present in the integral, and that will appear when the integral is evaluated. You could use the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for something like this, which basically says the derivative of the integral is the integral of the derivative (i.e. you just differentiate inside).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way
$$f(t)=t+\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \sin(x+t) dt \implies f(t)=t+ \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) (\sin x \cos t+\cos x \sin t) dt$$
$$f(r)=t+\cos t ~(\int_{0}^{\pi}  f(x) \sin x dx)+ \sin t ~ (\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \cos x dx) $$
So $$f(t)=t+A \cos t + B \sin t~~~~(*)$$
Where $$\int_{0}^{\pi} (x + A \cos x + B \sin x) \sin x ~dx=A~~~(1) \implies 2A-B\pi= 2\pi~~~(3)$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} (x + A \cos x + B \sin x) \cos
 x ~dx =B~~~(2) \implies 2A-B\pi=4~~~~(4)$$
We finally get $$A=\frac{4\pi-\pi^3}{4-\pi^2}=\pi,~~ B=\frac{2\pi(\pi-1)}{\pi^2-4}$$ from Eqs. (3) and (4).
Inserting them in (*), we get the solution of the integral equation.

Comment: Your $A$ can be simplified to $\pi$.

Comment: I had a similar method but I think you've found $A, B$ wrongly. Imo it should be $(0,-2)$. See [(Desmos)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xbifygz50q) with my curves in black and blue and yours in red.

Comment: I believe you have an error in the first line, where you should have $\displaystyle f(t)=t+\int f(x)\sin (x+t)\,\mathrm{d}\color{red}{x}$. This seems to lead to your later error.